# css pure arrows inside td tag

Tags: css

I have a table. Inside that table some td have the class "arrow". For the td that have this class I would like to put an arrow (triangle) on the left border of that td. I would like to use only css to achieve that. Note that I wish the arrow to start below the top border and end above the bottom border. I tried to apply several "pure css arrows tutorials" I found on the internet but I do not manage to make it work on td. I hope I was clear and I hope someone might help. Thank you in advance for your replies. Cheers. Marc.

http://cssdesk.com/PzASe

My HTML :

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>td1</td>
    <td class="arrow">td2</td>
    <td class="arrow">td three</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>td4</td>
    <td class="arrow">td five</td>
    <td class="arrow">td6</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

My CSS:

```
table{
  border-spacing: 0px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  text-align:center;
  vertical-align:middle;}

td{
  padding:10px;
  border:1px solid purple;}

.arrow:before { 
  content:'';
  position: relative; 
  top: 0; 
  left: -10; 
  border-top: 5px solid transparent; 
  border-bottom: 5px solid transparent; 
  border-right: 5px solid transparent; 
  border-left: 5px solid  black; 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is your target audience with this? Most of the CSS techniques for drawing shapes like triangles involve things like insert new elements, and advanced CSS properties (read: don't work in IE), I would suggest biting the bullet and using an old-fashioned background image.

If you're doing it as a proof of concept, and you don't care what browser a visitor is using, have you looked at [this tutorial on CSS tricks](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/)?

You would need to insert a `<div>` into those cells, and then apply styling like this:

```
.arrow div {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 10px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
    border-left: 10px solid blue;
 }
```

Comment: Hello chipcullen. I wanted to avoid that solution but I realize I can not do otherwise. I am not very happy with the result though. It does not look smooth : http://cssdesk.com/Kg8dx

Comment: Yeah, at that size, it may be hard to make it render smoothly, as you are relying on squishing CSS borders. That relies on the browser rendering engine, which won't know to 'anti-alias' - which would be needed to render smoothly. 

If you went with a background image, though, you could render a border with the triangle kick out, and in reality, don't have a left hand border at all in those TD's. That way the triangle would be rendered smoothly (in your image editor), but you get that kick out effect. Does that make sense?

Comment: Actually if I put a background-color equal to the triangle border color it looks much smoother... So I will stick with that solution I think.

Comment: If that works for your design - great! Lots of ways to skin this cat.

Answer (score 0):

Try this css. Your `td` was center aligned which added that odd space before your arrow. (see it in action here [css code](http://cssdesk.com/mCxJx)

```
table{
  border-spacing: 0px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  text-align:center;
  vertical-align:middle;}

td{
  padding:10px;
  border:1px solid purple;}

.arrow:before { 
  content:'';
  position: relative; 
  top: 0; 
  left: -10; 
  border-top: 5px solid transparent; 
  border-bottom: 5px solid transparent; 
  border-right: 5px solid transparent; 
  border-left: 5px solid  black; 
}
.arrow {
  text-align:left;
}
```

Comment: Hello Andei. Thanks for the alignment but this is not really the problem.The problem is that the arrow is not displaying properly. Thanks anyway...